# Is the Too Broad Flag being used Too Broadly?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I am going through that monstrous close queue now and I see too broad appears to be the catch-all flag for many users.  It is like the I am sure there is something wrong with this question I just can't quite put my finger on it flag.  Was it designed with this sort of leeway involved or is it being abused?

Comment: What makes you think it is used as a "catch-all flag"?

Comment: @Louis Based upon my experiences so far with the queue, it seems to be the reason most incorrectly applied and used a number of times in a general sense rather than to really mean the question asked is too broad.  Admittedly, I have only been at this for a week.  When asking, I was quite sure that there would others who disagree or would pick another as the catch-all, or perhaps even vigorously deny that there are catch-all reasons currently.

Comment: Can you give us some more concrete examples?

Comment: Now that is irony. Question about being too broad gets closed for being too broad...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4632451.  The problem here is that the user made no effort and gave no code example.  I would like to reopen it just so I can close it for the correct reason.

Comment: @demongolem Sometimes users do not have any coded example. see this question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255393/concept-of-broad-question

Comment: so your meta question about too broad flag being orverly used has been closed as to broad?. Not sure if i shoud laugh or..

Comment: Isn't it possible to run a query that shows the close votes distribution for questions that have the usual 5 close votes? I assume that if 'too broad' is often used incorrectly, there will be a significantly larger spread of vote reasons for question that have at least 1 'too broad' vote (e.g. very often 1 or 2 close votes together with 4/3 other reasons). That is still no *proof* of the OPs claim, but at leats it would give the question some substance.

Answer (score 2):

This problem will exist in any iteration of close vote reasons, because people who close questions tend to say, "Wow, that's just really...  *awful*" a lot, and TPTB keeps trying to discourage that. So close-voters always have to find some awkward close reason to use as a catch-all. Previously it was Not A Real Question, and there was something in the generation between that and current that filled the role.

Is this "good" behavior? Well, do you agree more with the close-voters or with the designers of the close reasons? If you dissent, is casting broadly used close votes good culture or obnoxious? This is all too philosophical for me, but I posted this as an answer since I think it's a pretty good description of what's going on.