# How to ask questions about complex systems without being too broad?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, needs-more-focus

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562129/what-actually-affects-compiled-c-code-performance) that was almost immediately flagged as too broad, and while I was writing this was downvoted to oblivion and deleted.

Screenshot for the <10k users here:
[image]

As I thought I had narrowed it as well as I could, I asked why in the comments, and the answer seemed to be that there were elements of the system I was asking about (how assembly code is executed), a full description of which would be necessary to completely answer my question, which I did not account for in my narrowing because I was unaware of their existence. I understand that under many circumstances I should be expected to have found out about these kinds of things through my own research. However in my case, none of the simple results included information about these unknown elements, as they either were overly simplistic and glossed over them, addressed slightly but significantly different specific problems to which the solutions did not involve said elements, or were similarly structured StackExchange questions that were also in the process of being downvoted into oblivion.

I was able to find an answer to my question from the comments, but if none of the downvoters had been kind enough to respond then I would be exactly where I left off with in incomplete understanding of the system, no knowledge that my understanding was incomplete, and with one more closed question to be added to a useless list of google search results.

Speaking as a question asker, if I have a question about a complex system which I do not fully understand, how can it best be asked to escape that cycle? As many similar, overwhelmingly upvoted questions show, it is in fact possible ([Why does gcc generate 15-20% faster code if I optimize for size instead of speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470873/why-does-gcc-generate-15-20-faster-code-if-i-optimize-for-size-instead-of-speed?rq=1), [Why does Python code run faster in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function?rq=1), and perhaps most spectacularly [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array?lq=1)).

Comment: Keep in mind all your upvoted examples are _older_ questions, when rules were a little more lax on what could and couldn't be asked. If those exact same questions had been asked today instead, they would've met the same fate as your question, more than likely.

Comment: 'If I compile it with -Os, it takes 0.38 s to execute this program, and 0.44 s if it is compiled with -O2 or -O3. These times are obtained consistently and with practically no noise (gcc 4.7.2, x86_64 GNU/Linux, Intel Core i5-3320M)' is not broad.

Comment: @Kendra And should they?

Comment: If a question doesn't fit the rules of the site, yes. Posted today, those would fall under "Too Broad" and be worthy of downvotes. Right _now_ they're useful questions, and have served a good purpose. But if they had been asked today, they wouldn't have hit that level of usefulness before they were handled as deemed appropriate by today's site rules.

Comment: @Kendra wow. Well, we've got the advocate for Lawful here, that's certain. Why does stack exchange exist?

Comment: Stack Overflow's purpose is to create a high quality repository of answers to programming questions. As you change sites on the network, the topic will change, but the main goal is the same: _high quality_ repository of questions and answers. As the site's grown, the rules have changed to try to best create that repository, by setting a standard for "high quality" that we want questions and answers to meet.

Comment: So why aren't those old questions flagged for deletion?

Comment: @P... _"So why aren't those old questions flagged for deletion?"_ Some of them are actually, some others are left as historically significant and locked.

Comment: Old questions are regularly closed.  There are over 11 million of them.  Want to help us find these broad yet still open questions?

Comment: You asked a reasonable question; the problem is that high-quality _answers_ are going to be long and complicated.  Short "_Yes, to a first approximation, but here's an example where GCC gets the loop control right but the loop body math wrong_" answers may technically answer the question, but they don't get to the heart of what you're asking.  The questions you cite are based around explanation of a specific example, limiting the scope of their answers (at the cost that the answers may not generalize beyond the example).

Comment: Also, lots of code is cache-capacity or cache-latency/memory-latency bound, not control-bound.  But some code really is compute-bound.  On x86 some code is decoder-bound.  General statements about performance are difficult to make.

Comment: @Will Well, there's two of them in my post, or one if you agree with Martin about what 'broad' means. Last one's protected unfortunately, so I can't do anything about that. I'd go ahead and flag the other two though, if it wouldn't be taking this experiment too far.

Comment: I 've come to this kind of situation a couples of times. I conclusion was: SO is like a creature; it has its either established or evolving characteristics. If one have to learn how to play with its. If there is something its doesn't like, one can choose to: (1) stop repeating it and bring the thing to other place; (2)  force with the power one have; (3) train it patiently; (4) understand its nature, and find other things to do with it; (5) pat oneself on the back and say "it can't understand me" or "my ego can't win its ego"...

Comment: @Kendra I think your comments describe how things are, but we act sort of convinced that all broad or easy questions stopping being asked sometime around 2010, and it's only specialized detail questions that are left for us to solve. This is arrogant and wrong and exactly how we operate.

Comment: @djechlin I don't know how you got that impression. It's not that they stopped being asked, it's that we found broad questions, or questions with large and broad answers, are a bad fit for the site. As for easy questions, there is _nothing_ wrong with easy questions being asked. The only reason for an easy, otherwise well-written, question to be closed would be as duplicate. I should know- Most if not all of my questions have been easy questions.

Comment: @Kendra occasionally an extremely "wrong" question slips through and gets a stellar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background it does bother me that we try really hard to prevent questions like that from being asked. I'm not convinced we're getting the balance right although with what a huge problem *terrible* questions are, I'm not sure how we can improve it.

Comment: @djechlin If you feel there needs to be a change in how we view certain types of questions, start a discussion about it. After doing research for previous discussions of course. The comments of this question are not the place to hash this out.

Comment: @Kendra as I said "I'm not sure how we can improve it." I definitely won't say well-received, old questions would be bad questions if they were asked today.

Comment: * old questions that would be closed today

Comment: @P... For future reference, don't start a post with *"I hate to ask such a general question"*. All you're doing there is asking people to close your question as too broad, even before they read the question. That's why your question was closed 3 minutes after being posted.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, I knew that typing it which was kind of why I thought I had to. I was hoping that if I acknowledged it I might get some tips on how to improve the question, I guess in retrospect I should probably have come here first.

Comment: This meta question is also too broad. You should have posted 'Why was my question deleted' or 'How could I have improved this question and got a better response'. The question as posted hides the fact that you want to discuss your specific question rather than start a general discussion of question design philosophy.

Comment: In addition to this I feel you are not going to win any friends with patronising remarks like the last sentence of your question and your second reply to @Kendra. You are relatively new to this site and you should assume good faith.

Comment: @Kendra, in my completely biased opinion, this particular question is much more "high quality" than 29384628583698th completely on-topic "halp! how do I <s>shoot web</s> match word at begining of string". It seems the system as it stands now doesn't really produces "repository of high quality", but that's topic for another discussion.

Comment: And now people are VTCing this meta question as "too broad"...

Comment: @jwg I disagree with your first comment, but agree partly with your second. I debated editing out the sentence, and decided not to so that it wouldn't seem as though I was being Orwellian about my mistakes. After reading your comment though I think I will remove it. Regarding my response to Kendra, I responded such because up to that point the only response they seemed to have to the question was an unsupported 'the rules are the only things that matter', which is the least helpful attitude possible in a meta discussion. And so I tried to inspire either further explanation or reconsideration.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Not the first time this has happened... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251519/is-the-too-broad-flag-being-used-too-broadly

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Speaking as a question asker, if I have a question about a complex system which I do not fully understand, how can it best be asked to escape that cycle? As many similar, overwhelmingly upvoted questions show, it is in fact possible (Why does gcc generate 15-20% faster code if I optimize for size instead of speed?, Why does Python code run faster in a function?, and perhaps most spectacularly Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?).

Those questions all are very tightly specified. They're about a very specific piece of code operating under specific circumstances. The answers may be complex, but the questions themselves are reasonably scoped.

You are talking about things in a very, *very* general way. That's what makes it too broad. If you want to ask questions about a complex topic, it still needs to be focused on something specific. Like a particular piece of code that is exhibiting particular behavior.

Your question is basically, "This is what I think are the prime factors surrounding performance. Am I right?" That's pretty broad, and there's no code in sight.

Comment: That is a very good point. I was focused on the broadness of the answers, rather than that of the questions.

Answer (score -21):

You posted a bad question. StackOverflow is not RequestATutorial.

You should accept this and focus on doing your own research which will allow you to understand the topic better, and also to ask more targeted questions which will get a better reception.

This is a better use of your time than to post two further meta questions about your bad question asking to have an extended debate about the rules.

Comment: Although there are plenty of questions posted here that are merely thinly-veiled rants, this seemed like a perfectly constructive inquiry to me. Maybe he was confused about the rules, but he was open to further clarification. I don't know about you, but that's the kind of user I want to *support*, not denigrate. Save the ire for the people who just don't care.

Comment: As Gray says, I think telling someone who is *asking how to improve* to leave meta is not constructive at all. In what way is he after a debate? He's asking why, not ranting about how bad it is. I think you're the one after an argument with this answer.